# PostGIS treating unique geometries as equal

Tags: postgis

I have two different geometries (albeit very closeby) that Postgres is treating as equal.

```
db=> select '0101000020E6100000C5BCD8C5FEF45DC0AFE29EF87B584740'::geometry = '0101000020E61000005A7CAFC6FEF45DC01A23C8F77B584740'::geometry;

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Can I dial-up PostGIS equality resolution so that these are unequal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html

```
select ST_Equals('0101000020E6100000C5BCD8C5FEF45DC0AFE29EF87B584740'::geometry
,'0101000020E61000005A7CAFC6FEF45DC01A23C8F77B584740'::geometry)
```

Returns False.

Answer (score 5):

PostGIS defines the `=` operator to test bounding-box equality rather than geometry equality (see [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_EQ.html)).

There have been discussions of changing this behavior, but I'm not aware of anything in the works.  (Refer to  https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2016-April/025769.html for a recent discussion.)